# ADT Plugin: Missing properties in layout editor

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm having trouble with eclipse ADT plugin. Everything was ok in Eclipse's layout editor, in both graphical and XML modes. I designed the GUI mostly from the graphical editor, for convenience.

At some point the Properties view broke. Now it only shows properties for the "View" class, and every other property from View subclasses are not shown (for instance, properties of ImageView are not shown). Properties for aligning inside RelativeLayout are also missing (for instance `alignParentTop`).

This is a "clean" eclipse install I use only for android, there are no other plugins installed (other than subeclipse). It has never failed me before. I've updated the SDK and also the plugin to the last version but it didn't fix this problem. Eclipse is v3.7 Indigo R2.
Also tried cleaning the project to no avail.

Have you seen this behaviour before? Is it possible to get the graphical editor back and fully working as expected without reinstalling everything again?

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATED:

I've traced the problem to a single layout XML. Other layout XMLs are working fine. And the problem is that I'm using the DrawerLayout as main layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

If I replace this layout for a regular `LinearLayout` everything returns back to normal. Still I've to find a solution, because every modificattion attempted on the graphical layout results in that element being removed. So this is probably a bug and not only it is inconvenient but also dangerous!

Comment: Is it like this in every project? Maybe you could make a clean testing project with some simple layout design if it's a problem with just one project or all of them.

Comment: @nio Yes it is a problem of this project only. I can open other projects with this same eclipse and everything is fine.

Comment: Then my guess is that your XML file is corrupt. Everytime the layout editor was not showing things properly, i had a problem with the XML file. Could you please post the XML listing?

Comment: @nio Please read my update.

Comment: This really MUST be a bug! I just encountered the same thing, reason as well is that the main layout is based upon a custom class, not a "standard" LinearLayout. But in my case it was something completely different, not DrawerLayout. Still, the effect is the same. Enclosed elements do not show all their properties, Layout properties for example are missing completely for TextViews. Splitting into several included layouts works around this, but that is NOT a fix for the bug!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by splitting the content of the DrawerLayout out into different files like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->
<include layout="@layout/activity_tab_content"/>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now I can edit the content of the drawer successfully in a separate editor.

Comment: I had the same problem with the DrawerLayout as well. The editor was acting craaaazy in all sorts of ways. Now I only add the DrawerLayout at the very end when I create a view.